# Ubuntu 21.10 changing default output and input devices after every reboot

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 21.10

Running Ubuntu 21.10 at the moment and noticed that it automcatically changes the default output and input devices even though I've set them differently. After settng my default output device to `Headphones - Built-In Audio` and `Micrphone - Blue Microphones` after a reboot the output device is set back to `Speakers - Blue Microphones` and input device to `HD Pro Webcam C920`. How do I make this change permanent?

I tried making changes to pulsaudio config file without luck.

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -Ei 'index:|name:'
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Generic_Blue_Microphones_LT_2110060932289D0203AE_111000-00.analog-stereo>
  * index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    index: 8
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
```

Per pulseaudio documentation:

```
### Make some devices default
# set-default-sink output
# set-default-source input
set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0
set-default-source alsa_output.usb-Generic_Blue_Microphones_LT_2110060932289D0203AE_111000-00
```

When I reboot the output device is Blue Yeti's speakers and the microphone is not active, the sound bar does not show it is reacting to sound. When I unplug the cable and plug it back in it is reacting to audio.

Comment: ubuntu 21.10 will reach EOL in July 2022 https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu Maybe time to upgrade to an LTS version?

Comment: I doubt it's going to change anything. I had the same issue on 21.04. I guess the most valid option for now is to just say 'goodbye' to Ubuntu...

Comment: why not create a bootable USB in the latest LTS v22.04 which will have the latest kernel and give that a try before simply giving up?

Comment: that will not work because the settings from a bootable USB are not permanent

Comment: Besides, is this how support for Ubuntu should look? Say that the OS will be soon end of life?

Comment: not my rules chum... read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @jedi could you find a solution? I'm experiencing exactly the same (Blue Yeti's speakers set to default on every reboot). I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 so I don't think the comments bellow to update the OS would be helpful.

Comment: @bazaglia Partially. If my memory serves me well I changed my device profile in `pavucontrol` from Duplex to Stereo but you'd have to check the exact names in the UI. I said partially because this solution only makes it so that the device is set as default after every boot but it doesn't solve the issue of the mic not taking any input so my mic still doesn't work after I boot up. I have to unplug the cable and plug it back in to make it work.